# Не скачивается файл в хроме

Tags: php

В Dlink DNS-320 установил Lighttpd & PHP 5,2 залил скрипт Veno File Manager 1.6.8 rus, все поставилось, загрузка папок происходит нормально, а вот скачивания почему то работает только в mozilla/5.0, а в хроме нет, с чем это может быть связано.

Comment: Может быть, [тут](http://i.imgur.com/iCY2z0H.png) стоит «Always block on this site»?

Comment: нет http://77.122.69.53:9090/?dl=3e879d509a452791fc422faeea05aec5 пишет ошибку vfm-downloader.php файл отсутствует но  mozilla/5.0 все нормально?

Comment: Можно, как обычно в таких случаях, изучить запросы и заголовки и поискать разницу. Для этого удобнее всего использовать Developer Tools, в обоих браузерах есть вкладка Network.